# Why does this PDO DB insertion with magic_quotes_gpc off still result in backslashes in db?

Tags: mysql, pdo, escaping, magic-quotes-gpc

On the server I'm using (running php_fastcgi5), there is an .htaccess file in the root directory containing this directive, to turn off magic_quotes_gpc:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

A phpinfo() output reports that the local value for magic_quotes_gpc is indeed off.  (The master value is however "on".)

I am not sure if this is reporting accurately, firstly because I read [this posting](http://drupal.org/node/1437998), and secondly because the following code using PDO prepared statements still ends up with backslashes inserted into the database record:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=my_database_name;charset=utf8', 'database_user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$output = '<p>Post some text which includes some apostrophes:</p><form name="form" action="test.php" method="post"><input type="text" size="60" name="string" value="The server\'s not behaving as it\'s supposed to." /><br /><br /><input type="submit" value="Post" /></form><br />----------<br />';

if (isset($_POST['string'])) {
  $PostedString = $_POST['string'];
  $InsertQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (string) VALUES (?)");
  $SuccessfulInsertion = $InsertQuery->execute(array($PostedString));
  if ($SuccessfulInsertion) {
    $ReadStatement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY `id`');
    $ReadStatement->execute();
    $ReadStatement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row = $ReadStatement->fetch()) {
      $ThisString = $row['string'];
      $output .= '<p>'.$ThisString.'</p>'.$CR;
    }
  }
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Does anyone know why text inserted into the database using this code still results in db records with slashes added before apostrophes?

Is it because PHP is running as php_fastcgi5 (i.e., is the .htaccess directive to switch off magic_quotes_gpc not working because of this)?  If so, is there a workaround? (I have no access to the php.ini file.)

Comment: If you `var_dump($_POST);`, is it escaped there? If so.... something fishy is going on on that server if it still claims `magic_quotes_gpc` is off. No auto-prepends or other code fiddling with data before this?

Comment: It looks like there are backslashes in your text: `value="The server\'s not behaving as it\'s supposed to."`

Comment: @Wrikken Yes, doing `var_dump($_POST);` shows the output to have back-slashes.  There is no other code than what I've set out above.

Comment: @Marcus Adams That's only because I used single quotes in PHP.  They have nothing to do with the backslashes that are output to the db - those appear only before any apostrophes entered. If I leave the text field blank and enter in the text with the apostrophes manually, the same result occurs.

Comment: @JohnDoe: so, problem not in this code, but earlier. If `phpinfo();` says no magic quotes, and no auto-prepend.... _something_ is inserting those quotes. Are you the server owner? If not, ask the owner whether he has installed / configured something that might do this.

Comment: @Wrikken Yes it's puzzling. phpinfo() reports that the local value of `magic_quotes_gpc` is Off (and the master value as On), though there is the issue discussed in the post I linked to above which muddies that up a bit.  I've asked the support of the hosting company who own the server but they have not been helpful; they do not seem to know the answer.  As I mentioned, I had some vague memory that it might have something to do with PHP being compiled as php_fastcgi5 not allowing the .htaccess directive, though I can't be sure of this and I can't find any reference to this idea.

Comment: If `.htaccess` wasn't read, the value would also be `off`, and the vulnerability is (luckily) only the `cgi`, NOT the `fastcgi` implementation. However, the reason for choosing fastcgi instead of php as a module is often custom settings & ownership per-customer, in other words, also with a custom `php.ini` file per customer. Is that something your hosting provider could provide for you?

Comment: Hm, I now read the value will sey `off` when it's one... That custom php.ini seems the way to go then.

Comment: The hosting company reports that there is only one php.ini file for the (shared) server; that magic_quotes_gpc value can only be changed via an .htaccess file; that "nobody else has reported this problem [I am] describing".  So what is wrong with my code above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

Magic_quotes_gpc - local: Off - master: On

But $_POST has slashes.

Also running fastcgi. I wonder if it's an issue with fastcgi?

We had to force it off with -d magic_quotes_gpc=off.